# What is the meaning of Capacity to shape the future

Tags: phrases

I want to know the interpretation of capacity to shape the future

Comment: Have you looked in a dictionary?

Comment: This phrase isn't an idiom or well-known phrase and each word means the dictionary definitions.

Answer (score 1):

As @MichaelHarvey said, please use a dictionary. I’ll try to get you started: “capacity,” “shape,” and “future” should all be looked up separately.